# checking if a string is contained in other string in shell

Tags: string, shell, if-statement, sh, contains

if I run this, it doesnt print yes.

```
if [s == [Ss]]
then echo "yes"
fi
```

However, if I write double `[]`, so will be like

```
if [[s == [Ss]]]
then echo "yes"
fi
```

it prints yes

I wonder WHY

Comment: You cannot use *character classes* (e.g. `[...]`) within `test` (synonymous with `[...]`). Only bash `[[ ... ]]` allows character classes within it.

Comment: It all depends on the result of the command `[s`.  Try executing `[s` directly (it's an odd name for a command, but perhaps you have an executable with that name), but  I would expect your first example to give an error similar to `[s: no such command`

Comment: Space error aside, `[` and `[[` are two different commands, and only `[[` supports pattern matching with the `=(=)` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, POSIX-shell does not allow the use of *character classes* (e.g. `[...]`) within `test` (synonymous with `[...]`). Only bash `[[ ... ]]` allows character classes within it.

If you have `coreutils` installed (about every distro does) you can still match a *character list* against the string returning the index (1-based) within the string of the first character in the character list. For your case you could use:

```
if [ $(expr index "s" "sS") -gt '0' ]; then
    echo yes; 
fi
```

Where `expr index "s" "sS"` is the usual form of `index string charlist`, which requires the use of `expr` before it.

If you are limited to POSIX shell, then you can sill use `expr string : regex` to match against a regular expression.

```
if [ $(expr "s" : '[sS]$') -gt '0' ]; then
    echo yes; 
fi
```

(**note:** the regex must match the entire contents of the string being tested against)

Comment: POSIX `expr` doesn't have an `index` subcommand. Use `expr s : '[sS]$'` instead.

Comment: @chepner You are right `match` (or `':'`) is the only POSIX `expr`. Ahah! is `coreutils` that proves `: match substr index length`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings, the double-bracket syntax features shell globbing. As you are trying to compare with both the upper case and lower case.
Also the double bracket syntax helps in Regex pattern matching.
 The condition you gave is similar to

```
if [[ "$stringvar" == *string* ]]; then
```

This means that an asterisk `(“*”)` will expand to literally anything, just as you probably know from normal command-line usage. Therefore, `if $stringvar` contains the phrase `“string”` anywhere, the condition will return true. Other forms of shell globbing are allowed, too. If you’d like to match both `“String”` and `“string”`, you could use the following syntax:

```
if [[ "$stringvar" == *[sS]tring* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

`[` doesn't support pattern-matching. Use `case` instead.

```
inp=s

case $inp in
  [sS]) echo "Matched s/S" ;;
  *) echo "Did not match s/S" ;;
esac
```